# how to replace certain word in table in R studio

Tags: r

Recently, I started learning R. I would like to replace certain word in table by other word in the same table.
For example, my table looks like

```
No. Fruits  Weight  Size
1   AB  200 L
2   AM  150 M
3   KD  50  S
4   KM  189 L
5   NA  260 L
```

I want to replace `NA` with word `Fruits` in this table. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a little dubious that your table actually looks like that; you have to work to get column names with spaces in them in R. Further, I'm not convinced it's a good idea to get rid of the `NA`s if they are, in fact, missing data. All that said, one option would be `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(\`No. Fruits\` = coalesce(\`No. Fruits\`, 'Fruits'))`

Answer (score 1):

The following creates data frame `df` with the sample data you provided:

```
df <- read.table(text = "No. Fruits  Weight  Size
1   AB  200 L
2   AM  150 M
3   KD  50  S
4   KM  189 L
5   NA  260 L", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and the following will replace the `NA` with `Fruits`

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 'Fruits'
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether that is the string "NA" or an actual `NA` (which, in R language, means "missing" or "error").  If it's the former, try

```
df$Fruits = gsub("NA", "Fruits", df$Fruits)
```

If it's the latter, try

```
df[is.na(df$Fruits),] = "Fruits"
```

Note that, if the `Fruits` column is a `Factor` which doesn't currently contain a "Fruits" entry, you might need to add this line at the top as well:

```
levels(df$Fruits) = c(levels(df$Fruits), "Fruits")
```